# convert string to active character

Tags: macros, catcodes, strings, easylist

in my book I will have to itemize a lot of things in different lists. That's why I want to reduce my commands to a minimum. This script is just part of a bigger macro.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\el}[1]{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}}

\el{
@ 1
@ 2
@ 3
    @@ 3a
    @@ 3b
    @@ 3c
}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
@ 1
@ 2
@ 3
    @@ 3a
    @@ 3b
    @@ 3c
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

When I pass the @-char to my macro it gets converted into a string so that it won't get recognized by easylist as an active character. How can I reconvert the @-char from string to an active character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure you gain something with this.

What you call a “catcode” is actually an *active character*. You have to activate the `@` before looking at the argument:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\newcommand{\el}{\begingroup\catcode`@=\active\doel}
\newcommand{\doel}[1]{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\el{
@ 1
@ 2
@ 3
    @@ 3a
    @@ 3b
    @@ 3c
}

\begin{easylist}[itemize]
@ 1
@ 2
@ 3
    @@ 3a
    @@ 3b
    @@ 3c
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative version (perhaps preferable, do some experiments):

```
\newcommand{\el}[1]{%
 \scantokens{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}}%
}
```

Comment: That's why I'm doing this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/domf0p.jpg For the left Page I have to type so little code now.